# What Microsoft product is used to draw a Relational Database for MS SQL?

Tags: ms-sql

What Microsoft product is used to draw a Relational Database for MS SQL?

For MySQL I have used MySQL Workbench what is similar for MS SQL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Microsoft Visio](http://visio.microsoft.com/en-us/preview/default.aspx) has support for ERD's. You can import the structure from an existing database as long as you can [make an ODBC data connection](http://forums.asp.net/t/1389812.aspx/1) to it from your computer.

Also see the following related answer from Stack Overflow: [Designing SQL database in visio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2178736/designing-sql-database-in-visio)